# Como manter posição de List/Menu em linha

Tags: css

Olá estou tentando deixar um List/Menu na mesma linha que a descrição de um determinado produto que apresento ao usuário mas como a linha usa um H1 a minha List/Menu acompanha o tamanho do texto, criei uma div nominada como direita para algumas tentativas sem sucesso.

```
        <h1 id="page-title"><a href="produtos.php?dep=<?php echo $row_rsDepartamento['id_departamento']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rsDepartamento['descricao'];  ?></a> &gt; <a href="produtos.php?dep=<?php echo $row_rsDepartamento['id_departamento']; ?>&sub=<?php echo $row_rs_Subdepartamento['id_subdepartamento']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rs_Subdepartamento['descricao']; ?></a>
        <div id="direita">
            <form action="produtos.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
             <select name="filtro" id="filtro" onChange="this.form.submit();">
               <option value="0">Ordenar por:</option>
               <option value="1">Popularidade</option>
               <option value="2">A-Z</option>
               <option value="3">Z-A</option>
               <input name="dep" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $dep; ?>">
               <input name="sub" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sub; ?>">
             </select>
            </form>
        </div>
      </h1>
```

O exemplo pode ser visto aqui:
[List/Menu](http://www.moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=1)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adventistapr/62j4ah84/1/)

Comment: Sua página deu : _"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"_

Comment: Olá @Wallace Maxters, acabei de editar a página, obrigado pelo comentário.

Comment: @adventistapr, tente sempre posta as suas duvidas com SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example - http://sscce.org/).
Acomselho que utilize o http://jsfiddle.net/ ou http://codepen.io/ para montar os seus exemplos.
desta forma fica até mais simples para nós modificamos os mesmos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente fazer algo do genero:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="esquerda breadcrumbs">Breadcrumbs</div>
    <div class="direita">
        <select name="filtro" id="filtro">
               <option value>Selecione um Filtro</option>
               <option value="1">Popularidade</option>
               <option value="2">A-Z</option>
               <option value="3">Z-A</option>               
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="direita">Ordenar por:</div>
</div>
```

Você pode acessar o exemplo completo em http://jsfiddle.net/70k6hx1h/1/